# Objective-C - inter-app communication

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app that list a list of files in a UITableView. These files are .ifc files (3D renderings) I have this other app that I downloaded called Field3D which displays downloaded .ifc files. Currently my app does download this file and I am looking for away to use UIActivityViewController so the user can share this file with the Field3D app. I was told that inter-app communication was the way to go, so I did some research and found this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html

Now it says under Sending Files and Data to Another App that all I have to do is the following:

```
- (void)displayActivityControllerWithDataObject:(id)obj {
   UIActivityViewController* vc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
                                initWithActivityItems:@[obj] applicationActivities:nil];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

but I don't believe this will work just like that because my code for the UIActivityViewController is very simliar

```
NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

            UIActivityViewController * activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[pdfData] applicationActivities:nil];

            activityController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;

            [self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

Can someone help me out and point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `UIDocumentInteractionController` to let the user open the file with Field3D.

An iOS app is distributed as an “IPA” file, which is just a ZIP file containing the app bundle and some other metadata files. I downloaded Field3D in iTunes and unzipped the IPA, then took a look at the app's Info.plist (using `plutil -convert json -r -o - Info.plist`) to see what document types it is registered for. Amongst others, it registers itself as a handler for `com.tekla.collada3d.ifc` with filename extension `ifc` and `com.tekla.collada3d.ifczip` with filename extension `ifczip`.

So if you have the file stored locally (presumably in your app sandbox's `Documents` or `Caches` directory) with an extension of `.ifc` or `.ifczip`, you should be able to let Field3D handle it just by presenting a `UIDocumentInteractionController` initialized with the URL of the (local) file. If you want, you can explicitly set the interaction controller's `UTI` property to `com.tekla.collada3d.ifc` or `com.tekla.collada3d.ifczip` instead of relying on the filename extension.

For more information, read [“Previewing and Opening Files” in *Document Interaction Programming Topics for iOS*](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PreviewingandOpeningItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010410-SW1).